# UIViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated not working

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to dismiss one ViewController and present another ViewController in its place.

This is what my code looks like

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];

            //load currentProjectListViewController
            currentProjectListViewController = [[CurrentProjectListViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CurrentProjectListViewController" bundle:nil];

                [self presentViewController:currentProjectListViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

however for some reason the view blinks quickly then stays the same and operates the same as usual.

I was woundering is my code incorrect? or is there something I should be looking for somewhere else in my code.. if so what should I keep an eye out for.

I have debugged the crap out of my app and havent been able to find the source of the issue.

On a side not occasionaly but only ever really seldomly will it load the next view! but I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you do like following:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{

    currentProjectListViewController = [[CurrentProjectListViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CurrentProjectListViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:currentProjectListViewController animated:NO completion:nil];

}];
```

or:

```
-(void)presentOtherVC {

    currentProjectListViewController = [[CurrentProjectListViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CurrentProjectListViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:currentProjectListViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
}

....

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{

        [self performSelector:@selector(presentOtherVC) 
               withObject:nil
              afterDelay:0.5f];

    }];
```

Indeed, when you call dismissViewController, it will take some time to have effect; in your code, *at the same time* (i.e., within the same run loop cycle) you are also asking the OS to present another view controller. Now, if you read `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` description, it states (bold mine):

> If you present several view controllers in succession, thus building a stack of presented view controllers, calling this method on a view controller lower in the stack **dismisses its immediate child view controller and all view controllers above that child on the stack**. When this happens, only the top-most view is dismissed in an animated fashion; any intermediate view controllers are simply removed from the stack. The top-most view is dismissed using its modal transition style, which may differ from the styles used by other view controllers lower in the stack.

So, you have clearly a conflict between dismissing a view controller while simultaneously presenting a new one. This explains why things do not work, and also why sometimes they do. It all depends on the timing between those conflicting tasks.

If you use `dismissViewControllerAnimated` completion handler like I have shown above, you can circumvent this problem.

Comment: Cool thanks for your reply. I have just tried using your peice of code which just did exactly the same thing as what was happening previously. Which suggests to me that the issue is with something else. I am going to continue debugging and hope I find something.

Comment: I see... I am pretty sure this is a race condition anyway... would you try the alternative I posted in my edited answer? It requires creating a new method, but it should work.

Comment: nope. I just debugged it again and it appears to be jumping back into my parser method just before gong into the new method. I will figure out whats going on there then see if that fixes it. I have this funciton which dose several requests in a row i recently changed this to do it in a different order I am now woundering if that is it... even though I have debugged it and thought it was corred.. Thanks for your help Ill let you know how i get on.. dont bother hangin round i might be a while LOL but if i come to any conclusions ill msg you back here.

Comment: Hi I have managed to debug my app ad have it running properly now but trying to use your code when i put a breakpoint inside the dismissViewControllerAnimated it never enters.. and the thread never makes it to the method... not sure why

Comment: This is the line causing the problem [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];  I am not sure what to do. But if i leave it out the UIViewController shows.. if I leave it in the new view never shows.